# cairo + openGL + Glut + VS 2010 + Windows 7

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, cairo

I'm pretty dump :) So could anybody help and write step-by-step manual, how to install "cairo", "glut" and use it in VS 2010 project (C++) on Windows 7?

PS: the most fun thing that i managed to do that without any problem in Linux.

Comment: Also this answer would help in the case of VS2008 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8985903/744859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know cairo, but setting up GLUT is rather straightforward.

1. Download [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)
2. Unpack the downloaded archive
3. Go the directory `unpack-dir/freeglut-x.x.x/VisualStudio2008`
4. Open the visual studio project
5. Rebuild the project for each target (release, debug) you want to create

This should create a DLL file and a lib file with the same name. Now if you want to create a new project that uses GLUT, just configure the project correctly:

1. Create new project
2. Create a main C/C++ file (otherwise, you won't be able to set the include settings)
3. Go to project settings (right click project -> **Configuration properties**)
4. **C/C++ -> General**: add the freeglut include directory to **Additional Include Directories**
5. **Linker -> General**: add the path to the built .lib (freeglut) file under **Additional Library Directories**
6. Under Linker (input) settings: add the name of the .lib file under **Additional Dependencies**

If you follow this setup, you should be able to use GLUT (`#include <GL/glut.h>`) in your code and it should compile nicely. Not sure how you can also add cairo, but it will probably be a very similar process.

Comment: tnx a lot, for your answer :)